# XPC Connection Interrupted

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

This isn't so much a code-related problem since I haven't added any new code for the past 2 hours, but I am using this cocoapod (https://github.com/ealeksandrov/EAIntroView) to make custom tutorial swipe views.

This is an update b/c I just realized something. The custom tutorial pictures I made in Sketch3 are only about 150kb, but the other pictures range from 3-9mb in size.

Could this be why I'm getting such a weird error?

This is what happens step by step:

1. Run app on iPhone 2. App opens, attempt to swipe right 3. App crashes and iPhone restarts.

This does not happen when I use the smaller size images, but I'm still not convinced that is what's causing the crashes.

Answer (score 2):

XPC Connection Interrupted Same issue m facing .Then m try to restart the xcode remove Deriveddata .

than it works fine .